# Twitter Bootstrap: Set data to the parent div of Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap Modal as a search box.
There are 3-4 divs from where User can call the modal and do the search. Search results are shown in table format on modal itself.
 When user clicks a row from search result, I have to take the selected row data and populate the parent div fields.
How would I determine the respective parent div which called search modal?
**Code**

```
    //initiates the modal
    $('#searchClient').click(function() {
                        clearTable();
                        $('#searchModal').modal('toggle');
                    });

    //reads data from clicked row
    $("#clientSearchResult").delegate("tr", "click", function(){
                        alert($(this).html());
//??Find out the parent div and populate selected data
                    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="clientSearchModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Client Search</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-inline">
                <input type="text" id="searchClientName" placeholder="Client Name">
                <input type="text" id="searchNumber" placeholder="Number">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="doClientSearch">Search</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="clientSearchResult">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Tax Id</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah so what's your problem? At the moment, your question is simply a statement

Comment: @Bojangles Sorry, There is a lot going on my head right now. Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're doing, but it sounds like you are trying to figure the source of the click event. If "searchClient" is the "parent divs" you are talking about, you should change their IDs to classes (`e.g. <div class="searchClient">`)

You could then do something like:

```
var parentClicked; //i'm global!

$('.searchClient').click(function(e) {
    parentClicked = e.target;
    ///etc....
 });
```